# Foreach output into two columns cshtml

Tags: c#, html, css, .net

My current code displays the output in one column ... I would like for it to display the output in two column. should I use something like flex grid or is there another way?

```
<div class="col-12 box-container">
     <div class="col-6">
       @foreach (var s in Model.StatusVM
       .Where(a => a.subHtmlID == x.HtmlID)
       .OrderBy(a => a.IDName)
       .ThenBy(a => a.SortOrder)
       .ThenBy(a => a.HID))
       {
           @Html.Partial("_MusicRow", s)
       }
     </div>
</div>
```

the current output looks like this...

```
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 4

<div class="col-12 box-container">
     <div class="col-6">
      <a class="status-row" href="#">item 1</a>
      <a class="status-row" href="#">item 2</a>
      <a class="status-row" href="#">item 3</a>
      <a class="status-row" href="#">item 4</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

trying to achieve

```
item 1   item 2
item 3   item 4
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML output please? Also the CSS that affects it.

Comment: You need to use `row` class if you're using Bootstrap to let the `col-` setting applied.

Comment: @ManojKumar i added the HTML output

Comment: Ok is there any delimiter inbuilt? To stop the for loop every 2nd item?

Comment: @ManojKumar no there is know delimiter inbuilt

Comment: @acctman Tell me whats your PartialView Looks like? show HTML.

Comment: @Valkyrie its displaying all the hyperlinks in vertically. one column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using bootstrap itself (if you want to do easily).Using Nested `Cols`, If you pass a `<div class="col-6"></div>` that surrounds your partial view the result will be met.

So:

```
<div class="row box-container">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">

            @foreach (var s in Model.StatusVM
            .Where(a => a.subHtmlID == x.HtmlID)
            .OrderBy(a => a.IDName)
            .ThenBy(a => a.SortOrder)
            .ThenBy(a => a.HID))
            {
                <div class="col-6">
                    @Html.Partial("_MusicRow", s)
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code speaks that you are using Bootstrap and if that is right then there is a silly mistake. change that parent class from `col-12` to `row`/ `row col-12`.

```
<div class="row box-container">
 <div class="col-6">
   @foreach (var s in Model.StatusVM
   .Where(a => a.subHtmlID == x.HtmlID)
   .OrderBy(a => a.IDName)
   .ThenBy(a => a.SortOrder)
   .ThenBy(a => a.HID))
   {
       @Html.Partial("_MusicRow", s)
   }
 </div>
```

Comment: I changed col-12 to row ... it still outputting one single column

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the CSS code behind your code but with your markup, we can make it like this:

```css
.box-container .col-6 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Wrap to next row after occupying width of 50% declared below */
}

.box-container .col-6 > a {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 box-container">
  <div class="col-6">
    <a class="status-row" href="#">item 1</a>
    <a class="status-row" href="#">item 2</a>
    <a class="status-row" href="#">item 3</a>
    <a class="status-row" href="#">item 4</a>
    <a class="status-row" href="#">item 5</a>
    <a class="status-row" href="#">item 6</a>
    <a class="status-row" href="#">item 7</a>
    <a class="status-row" href="#">item 8</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: although the solution works with static text it does not with the foreach statement. I removed the statement and tested with static text and it worked. I need a solution that would work with the foreach statement

Answer (score 0):

```
very easy just add/move col-6 inside for each like

    <div class="row text-center m-auto w-100 p-0">
foreach(var item in List)
{
    <div class="col-6 text-center w-50 m-0">
        <table class="table table-responsive table-striped"> 
        <tr>                           
                <td style="text-align: left">
            @item.Name
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                @item.Time
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
   
</div>
}
```